# How to obtain the PCIe ECAM base address under Linux?

Tags: linux, pci-e, sysfs

Is there a way to obtain the physical base address of PCIe ECAM space under Linux (e.g., via `sysfs` or `dmesg`)?

My intention is to use `devmem2` to exam the ECAM space, and compare the result with `lspci -x`. I am assuming that ECAM space can be accessed via MMIO (i.e., no I/O space is needed).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that using `cat /proc/iomem` gives the answer. And instead of using `devmem2`, I use `memtool` on debian.

On x86 (notice the `MMCONFIG` line):

```
    bruin@debian:/boot$ sudo cat /proc/iomem|grep -i pci
    000a0000-000bffff : PCI Bus 0000:00
    80000000-8fffffff : PCI MMCONFIG 0000 [bus 00-ff]
    90000000-fbffbfff : PCI Bus 0000:00
      c0000000-d1ffffff : PCI Bus 0000:04
      e0000000-efffffff : PCI Bus 0000:08
      fa000000-fb0fffff : PCI Bus 0000:04
      fb100000-fb1fffff : PCI Bus 0000:08
      fb200000-fb2fffff : PCI Bus 0000:05
      fb300000-fb3fffff : PCI Bus 0000:02

    root@debian:/boot# memtool md  0x80000000
    80000000: 2f008086 00100400 06000002 00000010                .../............
    80000010: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000                ................
    80000020: 00000000 00000000 00000000 102f17aa                ............../.
    80000030: 00000000 00000090 00000000 00000100                ................
    80000040: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000                ................
    80000050: fbffe001 00000000 00000000 00000000                ................
    80000060: 01029005 00000000 00000000 00000000                ................
    80000070: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000                ................
    80000080: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000                ................
    80000090: 0042e010 00008000 00000000 00793041                ..B.........A0y.
    800000a0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000                ................
    800000b0: 00000000 0000139e 00000000 00000006                ................
    800000c0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000                ................
    800000d0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000                ................
    800000e0: 00030001 00000008 00000000 00000000                ................
    800000f0: 00000000 00000000 00000009 00000000                ................

    root@debian:/boot# lspci -s 0:0.0 -xxx
    00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 DMI2 (rev 02)
    00: 86 80 00 2f 00 04 10 00 02 00 00 06 10 00 00 00
    10: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
    20: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 aa 17 2f 10
    30: 00 00 00 00 90 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00
    40: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
    50: 01 e0 ff fb 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
    60: 05 90 02 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
    70: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
    80: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
    90: 10 e0 42 00 00 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 41 30 79 00
    a0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
    b0: 00 00 00 00 9e 13 00 00 00 00 00 00 06 00 00 00
    c0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
    d0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
    e0: 01 00 03 00 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
    f0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

On ARM64 (notice the `ECAM` line):

```
    root@ampere:/boot# cat /proc/iomem|grep ECAM
    23fff0000000-23ffffffffff : PCI ECAM
    27fff0000000-27ffffffffff : PCI ECAM
    2bfff0000000-2bffffffffff : PCI ECAM
    2ffff0000000-2fffffffffff : PCI ECAM
    3bfff0000000-3bffffffffff : PCI ECAM
    3ffff0000000-3fffffffffff : PCI ECAM
    63fff0000000-63ffffffffff : PCI ECAM
    67fff0000000-67ffffffffff : PCI ECAM
    6bfff0000000-6bffffffffff : PCI ECAM
    6ffff0000000-6fffffffffff : PCI ECAM
    7bfff0000000-7bffffffffff : PCI ECAM
    7ffff0000000-7fffffffffff : PCI ECAM

    root@ampere:/boot# lspci -s 0:0:0.0 -x
    0000:00:00.0 Host bridge: Ampere Computing, LLC Device e100
    00: ef 1d 00 e1 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 06 10 00 00 00
    10: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
    20: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
    30: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

    root@ampere:/boot# memtool md 0x23fff0000000
    23fff0000000: e1101def 00000000 06000000 00000010                ................
    23fff0000010: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000                ................
    23fff0000020: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000                ................
    23fff0000030: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000                ................
    23fff0000040: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000                ................
    23fff0000050: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000                ................
    23fff0000060: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000                ................
    23fff0000070: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000                ................
    23fff0000080: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000                ................
    23fff0000090: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000                ................
    23fff00000a0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000                ................
    23fff00000b0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000                ................
    23fff00000c0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000                ................
    23fff00000d0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000                ................
    23fff00000e0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000                ................
    23fff00000f0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000                ................
```